# Execute a python file with arguments with PyScripter

Tags: python, pyscripter

I have a piece of python code.

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

I use PyScripter IDE for Python 2.7, but not sure how to pass the arguments with it, there is a Python
Interpreter window on the bottom of the IDE.

[image: ide]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution by myself. Click Run Menu will find the command line parameters. Then clicking it to input what you want.

[image]

Comment: I have just started to work with PyScripter. I have created a project, I have a PY file opened but Run options are all greyed!!! What do I need to do ???